# How to enable closing of calendar when the same date is chosen kendo-datepicker Angular?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-datepicker

I have a `<kendo-datepicker/>`. It works perfectly, however it does not give a chance to select the previous date twice.

For example, if I choose the following date `1.1.2018`, then `<kendo-datepicker/>` closes with selected date. It is okay.
However, if I want to select the same date `1.1.2018`, then `<kendo-datepicker/>` does not close with selected date.

[You can reproduce this behaviour at Basic Usage of Overview of](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/#toc-calendar-templates) `kendo-datepicker`.

Is it possible to choose the same date(`1.1.2018`) after I chosen the date(`1.1.2018`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to handle click event at the day of calendar and use `toggle` method on `kendo-datepicker` to collapse calendar.

So we have `kendo-datepicker`:

```
<kendo-datepicker #kendoDataPicker>
    <ng-template kendoCalendarCellTemplate let-date>
        <div (click)="handleClickCell(kendoDataPicker, date)">
            {{date.getDate()}}
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-datepicker>
```

and `JavaScript` code:

```
handleClickCell(kendoDataPicker : any, selectedDate: any){
    if( kendoDataPicker.hasOwnProperty('_value')
        && typeof( kendoDataPicker._value)!=='undefined'
        && typeof( selectedDate)!=='undefined'
        && selectedDate.toString() === kendoDataPicker._value.toString()
      ){
            kendoDataPicker.toggle();
    }
}
```

It is so cool that `toggle()` method of `kendo-datepicker` method can work out whether calendar should be collapsed or not.